# SSH Tunnel as a Windows Service

Tags: ssh, windows-service, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I want to set up an SSH tunnel to run as a Windows service, I need to be able to set it up using only the command line so this counts out any software that doesn't include a command line version.

What tools are available for Windows that I could use to do this?

Answer (score 4):

If your Windows system is running an SSH server, you can establish a reverse tunnel starting the connection from the other side.

There are several SSH servers available for Windows, for example [**copssh**](http://www.itefix.no/copssh/). On the other side you could use [**autossh**](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) for making sure that the tunnel gets re-established in case that the connection between client and server is lost.

In this way, instead of having to run an ssh client as a service on Windows, you'd need to run an ssh server like the one I mentioned.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, i'll look into this. Thanks

Comment: @mfriedman: Would you still recommend copssh today? Their website says the free version is outdated.

Answer (score 4):

**Bitvise WinSSHD**

I've used WinSSHD from Bitvise and had really good luck with it in the past.

Once of the nice things I like about it is when you have a server out of control and can't get into it via VNC because its pegged at 100% CPU or out of memory and thrashing the virtual memory you can always get in with SSH to issue a reboot command.

http://www.bitvise.com/download-area

I haven't installed it (fresh) in a while so I'm trying to remember if it supports straight command line or not.  You'd have to take a look.

Comment: We have several servers that maintain SSH connections as a windows service. I use NSSM to configure the windows service. It works great.

Answer (score 2):

You could try PuTTY Tray

http://haanstra.eu/putty/

Not a windows service, but close enough. You can have it start a saved profile from the command line with

```
puttytray.exe -load "<profile name>"
```

If you login automatically with key-authentication, you can easily configure it to reconnect on disconnect and be visible only as tray icon.

Comment: So, what does one need to do other than add this line to the list of 'Run' commands on login? Where do you configure it to reconnect-on-disconnect and start up minimized-to-tray?

Comment: It's just a fork of the regular PuTTY with extra options available. e.g The Window|Behavior tab has an extra panel for "Adjust the icon" where you can set "Show tray icon: On start". The Connection tab has "Attempt to reconnect on connection failure" etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using FreeSSHD for some time with much success.  It can run as a service, supports certificate login, and full tunneling...

Answer (score 2):

I use [cygwin](http://cygwin.com)'s [openssh](http://cygwin.com/packages/openssh/) package to do this with great success.

The openssh package includes an SSH server, `sshd`, that can easily be installed as a Windows service using the script `ssh-host-config` and then simply starting it using the Windows command `net start sshd`.  *Complete details are omitted simply for the sake of brevity...*

[Gina Trapani](http://lifehacker.com/people/Gina/posts/) posted [step-by-step instructions](http://lifehacker.com/205090/geek-to-live--set-up-a-personal-home-ssh-server) on [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com) now a few years old but, as far as I can tell from a quick scan, remain 100% applicable and accurate.

Comment: How are you using `sshd` to have a tunnel up constantly? The page you linked to does not mention tunnels.